# Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)' failed. Aborted (core dumped) in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-20.04

I have followed below page for ubuntu 20.04 set up for backend. https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-svn-server-on-ubuntu-debian/ I'm able to get successful response from server but same configuration is giving error via cli. Versions I'm using : pysvn - 1.9.9, natspy - 2.0.0rc5, nastserver - 2.3.3, svn - 1.13.0. When I'm trying to do checkout using
svn checkout http://localhost/svn/se/ se

I'm getting below error

Redirecting to URL 'http://localhost/svn/se/':
svn: /build/subversion-owKwd0/subversion-1.13.0/subversion/libsvn_subr/dirent_uri.c:1562: uri_skip_ancestor: Assertion `svn_uri_is_canonical(child_uri, NULL)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)' [image]

I tried several options, but still error is there. Can someone please help me.

I tried few options like local module load in apache2, different location/alias of repository in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf, but still same issue.